# Sprite Texture not dividing the pieces from the image C++

Tags: c++, textures, sprite, sfml, chess

Good day, I am trying to create a chess game from scratch using SFML the problem I am having is I end up with the picture attached below instead of having the chess piece by piece. right now I am not worried about the functionality of the game or the user command all I want is to run my code and see the normal chessboard.

This is what my code output:

[image: my problematic output]

and this is my **main.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <time.h>
using namespace sf;

int size = 56;
Sprite f[32];
int board[8][8] =
{ -1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-3,-2,-1,
 -6,-6,-6,-6,-6,-6,-6,-6,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1 };

void loadPosition() {
    int num = 0 ;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            int n = board[i][j];
            if (!n)continue;
            int x = abs(n) - 1;
            int y = n > 0 ? 1 : 0;
            f[num].setTextureRect(IntRect(size * x, size * y, size, size));
            f[num].setPosition(size * j, size * i);
            num++;
        }
}

int main()
{
    RenderWindow game(VideoMode(453, 453), "Suhaib-Chess");
    Texture t1,t2;
    t1.loadFromFile("img/pieces.png");
    t2.loadFromFile("img/board0.png");
    Sprite s;
    Sprite sBoard(t2);
    s.setTexture(t1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)f[i].setTexture(t1);
    loadPosition;

    bool isMove = false;
    float dx = 0;
    float dy = 0;

    while (game.isOpen()) {
        Vector2i position = Mouse::getPosition(game);
        Event e;
        while (game.pollEvent(e)) {
            if (e.type == Event::Closed) 
                game.close();

            if(e.type == Event::MouseButtonPressed)
                if(e.key.code == Mouse::Left)
                    if (s.getGlobalBounds().contains(position.x, position.y)) {
                        isMove = true;
                        dx = position.x - s.getPosition().x;
                        dy = position.y - s.getPosition().y;
                    }
            if (e.type == Event::MouseButtonReleased)
                if (e.key.code == Mouse::Left)
                    isMove = false; 
        }
        if (isMove == true) s.setPosition(position.x - dx, position.y - dy);
        game.clear();
        game.draw(sBoard);
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)game.draw(f[i]);
        game.display();

    }
    return 0;
}
```

### picture i am trying to use:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to `board0.png` also?

Answer (score 1):

The `board` array initialization seems wrong. Try it again with something like this:

```
    int board[8][8] = {
      { -1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-3,-2,-1 },
      { -6,-6,-6,-6,-6,-6,-6,-6 },
      {  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
      {  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
      {  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
      {  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
      {  6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
      {  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1 }
    };
```

Explanations: you obviously are trying to declare a two dimensional array, yet you initialize it with one huge 64 items array instead of an array of 8 arrays of 8 items. It later mess up your positions while in the `loadPosition` method.

Your project looks promising!